# How do I connect Web App to Storage Account Container and utilize it to serve files?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-authentication

In the Web App I configured the System-Assigned Identity and connected it to the Storage Account assigned as Storage Account Contributor. How do I reference from the Web App to the Storage Account so that the files will be served from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your application in Web-App Service. It executes the web app in the context of Managed Identity Account and there will not be an issue accessing containers & files.